# Android modify video resolution

Tags: android, video, resolution

I have an app in Android (API 8), that gets a video from a source that I cannot control.

I need to set the video that I get to a specific resolution (640 * 360).

How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just make your VideoView height and length in the ratio of 640:360.

Comment: I need to modify the actual file

Comment: I think its quite tough to do so, you can try but i was having the same problem , in my app i want to play videos in square format but the videos was not in 1:1 format so at the end i crop the videos at server side to make it 1:1 resolution. Tell me what you actually want i will suggest you something.

Comment: Thanks, I may have to do it server side.

Comment: yes you can crop the video on server side using FFMPEG , or you can programatically set the VideoView height and width in the required 640:360 ratio , if you think i provide an usefull answer please dont forget to vote :P

Comment: I am still looking for an answer that will allow me to compress the video size, android side.